# Class object and class type in Python

Tags: python, class

I am new to Python and I have a question about OOP. So, when we create a class we write "object" in parentheses.  For example,

```py
class My(object):
```

I have read somewhere that this means that the class inherits from the `object` class in Python. But I also have read that every class we create is an instance of the `type` class. So my question is the `object` class the same as the `type` class and, if yes, why, when ask Python to print the type of a class, it returns `<class 'type'>` and not `<class 'object'>`. Also, why can’t we write

```py
class My(type):
```

if the `object` class and the `type` class are the same?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18345827/why-does-inheriting-from-object-make-a-difference-in-python or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015417/why-do-python-classes-inherit-object

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two relationships here: *instance of* and *subtype of*. For a non-programming analogy, you can think about the difference like this. A particular apple sitting on a desk is an *instance* of "apple". It's an example of an apple, that particular one. On the other hand, "apple" as a concept is a *subtype of* "fruit". Every apple is a fruit. It wouldn't be accurate to say that the particular apple sitting on your desk is a subtype of anything, because it's a specific one. And it wouldn't make sense to say the concept of "apple" is an instance of "fruit", because it's not.

Every class you define in Python is a *subtype* of `object`, which is the type of all types. The class *itself* is also an object in Python, and its type is `type`. The latter can be used to do some clever metaprogramming, but that's advanced Python that you probably don't need to be messing with at this stage.

```
class Foo(object):
  pass

assert isinstance(Foo, type) # Foo is a type
assert issubclass(Foo, object) # Foo is a subclass of object
assert isinstance(Foo, object) # Every type (and everything in Python) is an object
assert isinstance(Foo(), Foo) # A specific foo is a Foo
assert isinstance(Foo(), object) # A specific foo is an object
```

For right now, as you're learning Python, it's pretty safe to just forget `type` exists. It's fancy and complicated and used for some really sophisticated metaprogramming tricks. For now, just use `object` and assume classes are some magical thing, and learn how to use them. You can learn the gritty details of how they work once you have a firm foundation.